# Is it possible to exclude fields from inline editing?

Tags: visualforce, formatting, inlineeditsupport, outputtext, outputfield

With visualforce, I'm using `<apex:inlineEditSupport />` inside e.g. `<apex:pageBlockTable>` quite often. It makes all outputFields editable. Fine. Now, is there a way to exclude some fields from being editable, e.g. you have {!sample__c.startDate__c} and {!sample__c.endDate__c} and want only startDate__c to be editable?

I know, there is `<apex:outputText>` which does exactly that, but `<apex:outputText>` can't handle localized dates as you will find on various places:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=visualforce+date+format
Without further investigation, I simply assume outputText will also end up in mess when it comes to localized time, numbers, currency and so on. In short, for most of my use-cases outputText simply sucks in the way it seems to be intentionally designed for now.

So I think a have to stick with outputField, which does all the localizations like a charm - but then I have to find a way to somehow **break** the inline-edit for some exceptions, which I want not to be editable. Probably I'll find it when a start to play around with the JS for a while... but I'm just wondering if anyone found it already? Clean, less-hackish approaches preferred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Docs.... [Reference](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_inlineEditSupport.htm)

Can't you just wrap set your specific fields you want to disable?

IE:

```
     <apex:outputField value="{!contact.firstname}">
          <apex:inlineEditSupport disabled="false"/>
     </apex:outputField>
     <apex:outputField value="{!contact.lastname}">
          <apex:inlineEditSupport disabled="true"/>
     </apex:outputField>
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot @DoubleA, his I was looking for! I'll give it a try and come back with the results.

Comment: Yes @DoubleA this exactly is what I was looking for. It works! thx

Comment: @UweHeim Np, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured a working interim approach. But I'm only half happy with it...

Having to following nesting:

apex:page > apex:form > apex:pageBlock > apex:pageBlockTable > apex:pageBlockTable > apex:column > apex:outputField

I marked the column with a class

```
<apex:column styleClass="noInlineEdit" >
```

Then, after the DOM is loaded, I do remove the inline-editing mechanism like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.setTimeout( function(){ 
        $(".noInlineEdit .inlineEditWrite span").unwrap();
    }, 1000);
});
```

It's not good, it's not nice, it's hackish, but works. Better solutions are highly appreciated, because I'm looking for an reusable pattern.